# Отформатировать информацию в виде определений. Где ошибка?

Tags: html

```html
<dt>HTML </dt>
<dd>
  Стандартна мова розмітки веб-сторінок в Інтернеті. Більшість веб-сторінок створюються за допомогою мови HTML. Документ HTML оброблюється браузером та відтворюється на екрані у звичному для людини вигляді.
</dd>

<dt>CSS</dt>
<dd>
  Спеціальна мова, що використовується для опису сторінок, написаних мовами розмітки даних.
</dd>
```

Comment: Наверное в том, что вы забыли закрыть теги `html`и `head`

Comment: @vantal
Это ошибки форматирования. Я тоже сначала удивился, зачем нам вырезки из википедии об html и css

Comment: а что не так с форматированием сейчас?